What is the formula that connects the average distance to the nearest point and the average number of points per unit volume?
We have an infinite 3D space with points randomly disseminated inside it.
Let $p$ be the average number of points per unit volume.
Let $d$ be the average distance to the nearest point.
What is the formula that connects $p$ and $d$? The formula doesn't have to be exact. An approximation would do.
Here's how I tried to tackle this problem:
The average number of points in a sphere of radius $d$ and volume $\frac{4}{3} \pi d^3$ is $1$.
Therefore, $p = \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3} \pi d^3}$
This formula can't be the exact formula, but it's probably a good approximation, right?

How did you get the average number points in a sphere of radius d to be just one point? Because it's average, we can have a number of points with average distance d around a center point, right?  Especially if you imagine the points to be around the center with no point at the center

Your formula is pretty good approximation. Even better approximation can be achieved in the following way. Assume that distribution of points is uniform and uncorrelated, so that it obeys the Poisson statistics. This means that the probability to find the nearest neighbor to a point at a distance $r$ reads:
$$
p(r)=4\pi r^2\rho\, e^{-\frac43\pi r^3\rho},
$$
so that the average distance to the nearest point is:
$$
d=\int_0^\infty r\cdot p(r)\,\mathrm dr=\frac{\Gamma(\frac43)}{\left(\frac43\pi\rho\right)^\frac13}.
$$
From this one obtains:
$$
\rho=\frac{\Gamma^3(\frac43)}{\frac43\pi d^3},
$$
which differs from your result by a factor $\Gamma^3(\frac43)\approx 0.712073$.
